# Difference between add_form and form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm currently reading a book on Django and reached the point where the author is creating a custom user model using the following code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin): 
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm 
    form = CustomUserChangeForm 
    model = CustomUser

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

could someone possibly explain to me what is the difference between `add_form` and `form`?

(if anyone could also tell me why we include both `CustomUser` and `CustomUserAdmin`in `admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)` that would be great)

thank you very much for your help!

Comment: As the name suggests, the `add_form` is used to create a *new* user, the `form` to *change* the data of an existing one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In short**: the `add_form` is used when you construct a *new* `CustomUser`, whereas the simple `form` is used to *change* data for an *existing* `CustomerUser` object.

The **`UserAdmin`** class overrides the `get_form(..)` method, as we can see in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L72):

> ```
> def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
>     """
>     Use special form during user creation
>     """
>     defaults = {}
>     if obj is None:
>         defaults['form'] = self.add_form
>     defaults.update(kwargs)
>     return super().get_form(request, obj, **defaults)
> ```

Now the `get_form` itself of the **`ModelAdmin`** class (the superclass of `UserAdmin`) invokes the `modelform_factory(..)` with a dictionary of attributes, as we can see in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L661):

> ```
> def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
>     # ...
>
>     defaults = {
>         'form': form,
>         'fields': fields,
>         'exclude': exclude,
>         'formfield_callback': partial(self.formfield_for_dbfield, request=request),
>         **kwargs,
>     }
>
>     if defaults['fields'] is None and not modelform_defines_fields(defaults['form']):
>         defaults['fields'] = forms.ALL_FIELDS
>
>     try:
>         return modelform_factory(self.model, **defaults)
>     except FieldError as e:
>         raise FieldError(
>             '%s. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class %s.'
>             % (e, self.__class__.__name__)
>         )
> ```

That dictionary is updated with parameters that are passed as named arguments. So with `form=self.add_form`. This thus results in using a *different* form: the `add_form`.

This can be useful if we, for example, only want to be able to update specific fields when we *update* a `CustomUser`.

Note that only the `UserAdmin` has such `get_form` override, a `ModelAdmin` itself *has no* `add_form` to the best of my knowledge, and thus specifying such attribute will not make a difference.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answers, could you just clarify a bit on the `admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)` part why do we register both `CustomUser` and `CustomUserAdmin`. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So as far as I understood if we are specifying the `form`attribute we should also specify `add_form`

Comment: @Fozo: we do not register both, we register a *link*. We register for the `CustomUser` the modeladmin `CustomUserAdmin`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#the-register-decorator

Comment: @Fozoro: no, this is specific for the `UserAdmin`, note that only for that class, it "overrides" the form selection.

Comment: Yes excuse me that's what I meant if we specify a form in the UserAdmin we should also specify a add_form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186945/discussion-between-fozoro-and-willem-van-onsem).